# Storing Python scripts on a webserver

Tags: python, hosting

Following on my previous question, if I have some hosting how can I put a python script on their that I can then run from there?  Do I need to do something special to run it/install something?
EDIT-Clarification-I would like to be able to upload the script which does stuff on the internet-no data is stored on my computer.  I then need to schedule it to run once a day.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step use case that describes what you want to do.  "Run a script from there" doesn't mean much.  Where does the script execute?  On your local PC?  On the server?  Where does the data exist?  On your local PC?  On the server?  What would you like to do?  Double-click an icon on your local PC?  Fill in a web-page form?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure your hoster system supports Python.

You can ask them about that.

To run the script once it is there, you can act in several ways, depending on what you want to do.

You can have your server side language to invoke it (i.e. from the backend of a web page), or if you have a shell access to the machine you can invoke it manually.

Btw, very often hosting providers give a scheduling tool (i.e. an interface for crontab or at) via the hosting plan administration panel, which you could use to start your script.

First thing, anyway, you have to ask your hoster and check Python availability.

Answer (score 0):

Usually python is already installed, but it depends on your hoster. Ask them.